# NAMESPACE issue: multiple packages import and export an identical function

Tags: r, package

I am writing a small package to do some routine data analysis and I wish to include some easy mapping functions. My package imports `tidyr`, `dplyr`, and `leaflet` (from RStudio on Github). When I build or load my package I get the warning:

```
replacing previous import by ‘leaflet::%>%’ when loading ‘MyPackage’
```

Looking at the NAMESPACE files of `leaflet`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`, I find that all three have

```
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
```

and

```
export("%>%")
```

So basically all 3 are importing and exporting the same function from the `magrittr` package. Is there some way I can resolve this within may package so that the warning is no longer generated (not just suppressed)? Is it something I should just ignore?

Comment: Please show your NAMESPACE file. Looks like you are importing all functions of these three packages? Simply don't do that. Import only the functions you need.

Comment: Correct I am importing everything - mostly to simplify things for me as I add more functions to the package. If I have to go to function by function I can, but I was hoping to avoid having to keep track of that as I add on more functions.

Comment: Importing functions that are not needed is somewhat bad practice.

Comment: If I change to function by function importing, how do I handle `%>%`? Just import it myself from `magrittr`?

Comment: That's what I would do. But, of course, I don't use any package that tries to make me use piping.