# Why does R report a namespace conflict for identical functions?

Tags: r, namespaces, shiny

I'm trying to create a list of namespace conflicts between packages in R, but the `conflicts()` function has some strange behavior, for example with the function `p` in the packages `shiny` and `htmltools` (which `shiny` imports):

```
> require(shiny)
> ## print source from shiny namespace...
> shiny::p
function (...) 
tags$p(...)
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
> require(htmltools)
> ## print source from htmltools namespace...
> htmltools::p
function (...) 
tags$p(...)
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

So the source for `p` is exactly the same, and is even from the same namespace for both of these packages (the help files are also identical), but if you run `conflicts(detail = TRUE)`, this function is listed as a conflict between the two packages. Why is this listed as a conflict, and is there a way to detect "conflicts" of this type? Is it related to the fact that you can directly call the function from either the `shiny` or `htmltools` namespace?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30626904/2679518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `conflicts` simply checks for names that are contained in more than one package on your search path. It does not check whether the actual objects that are denoted by these names are the same or not.

You can look at the name of the objects in the namespace of a package using `objects()` (which is also used inside `conflicts()`) or `ls()`. For example:

```
head(objects("package:shiny"), 10)
 ## [1] "a"                "absolutePanel"    "actionButton"     "actionLink"       "addResourcePath" 
 ## [6] "animationOptions" "as.shiny.appobj"  "basicPage"        "bootstrapPage"    "br"
```

If you run

```
which(objects("package:shiny") == "p")
which(objects("package:htmltools") == "p")
```

you will see the namespaces of `shiny` and `htmltools` both contain an object by the name of `p`. `conflicts` simply checks for all the names that appear in more than one namespace in `search()` and `p` is one of these, if you have `shiny` and `htmltools` attached.

To figure out why `shiny` contains a function that is acutally in the namespace of `htmltools`, you can look at the `NAMESPACE` file in the source of `shiny`. It contains the following lines

```
export(p)
import(htmltools)
```

`export` makes a function visible to someone who uses a package. So, it is the *exported functions* that you can call after you have attached a package with `library()`. `import(htmltools)` makes sure that all the *exported functions* in `htmltools` can be used by functions  in `shiny`. It does, however, not make functions from `htmltools` available to someone who runs `library(shiny)`.

Because `shiny` *imports* all the functions from `htmltools` (including `p()`) and then also *exports* `p()`, `p()` (from `htmltools`) is visible after `library(shiny)`.

You can check whether two conflicting objects are actually the same using `identical()`. This will show you that the function `p()` in `shiny` and `htmltools` is the same:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
identical(htmltools::p, shiny::p)
## [1] TRUE
```

On the other hand, the `dplyr` defines a function `filter()` that differs from the one in `stats`:

```
library(dplyr)
identical(dplyr::filter, stats::filter)
## [1] FALSE
```

Finally, let me propose a way to check, whether some conflict (that is, a name that appears in several attached packages) is a "real" conflict. By "real", I mean that the objects that share a name are *not* the same. So, `filter()` in the above example would be a "real" conflict, while "p" is not. The following function returns `TRUE` for a "real" conflict and false otherwise:

```
is_real_conflict <- function(conf_obj) {

  # get list of all conflicts
  conf_all <- conflicts(detail = TRUE)
  # get names of packages that contain an object with name conf_obj
  conf_pck <- names(conf_all)[sapply(conf_all, function(pck) conf_obj %in% pck)]
  # get the actual objects associated with these names
  objs <- lapply(conf_pck, function(ns) get(conf_obj, envir = as.environment(ns)))
  # compare each of the objects to the first one
  comp <- sapply(objs, identical, objs[[1]])
  # the following returns FALSE only if all the objects are the same
  return (!all(comp))
}
```

You can check all the conflicting names in one go by using

```
sapply(conflicts(), is_real_conflict)
```

Comment: Very clear and thorough answer! As an additional detail for future readers, it seems that `identical()` will return `FALSE` even if the function differences are syntactically meaningless. For example, if you define 
    `F <- function(x) return(x);
    G <- function(y) return(y);
    Z <- function(x) return( x )`,
`identical(F,G)` and `identical(F,Z)` will both return `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. `identical()` does not check whether two functions would give the same result for identical  inputs.